# Regex to check if whitespace present?

Tags: javascript, regex

Seems pretty simple, but cannot figure out why this javascript code isn't working returning false, when expecting true) - I'm guessing it has got to do something with the escape characters? Could someone please help me write a JS block that will return true if whitespace present?

```
var inValid = new RegExp("[\s]");
var value = "test space";
var k = inValid.test(value);
alert(k);
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need the brackets, you would need to escape the backslash (if using the string form) and the built-in regex syntax is easier because you don't have to escape backslashes when using the built-in regex syntax.

```js
var inValid = /\s/;
var value = "test space";
var k = inValid.test(value);
alert(k);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to match *something* there, but no whitespace:

```
alert(/^\S+$/.test(value));
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the backslash if you are creating your RegExp object from a string literal:

```
var inValid = new RegExp("[\\s]");
```

Alternatively you can just use the following:

```
var inValid = /\s/;
```

This uses a regular expression literal so the escaping of the backslash is not necessary, and there is no need for the character class here so I dropped the square brackets as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need a double escape character:

one for the "s" and one for the "\" itself:

```
var inValid = new RegExp("[\\s]");
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var inValid = /^/\s/;
var value = "test value";
var k = inValid.test(value);
alert(k);
```