# Validate White Space Strings

Tags: javascript

I am using regular expression to see if a string is nothing like "" or all white space like "    "

my regular expression is this:

```
/\s/
```

but is only working for when the input is nothing like "". How can I modify it to also check for all whitespace inputs like "    "

Comment: Try `/^\s+$/`, this includes start and end, and one or more whitespace characters in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a string is not empty and it's not just white space with :

```
if (str !== null && str.trim() !== '') {
  console.log('not empty');
}
```

or with regex :

```
const str = '   '
const regex = /^\s+$/;
const invalid = regex.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048148/regex-to-check-if-whitespace-present) your regex should work

```js
var inValid = /\s/;
var value = " ";
var k = inValid.test(value);
alert(k);
```